# Functional Python - Multiple Dictionaries to One Dictionary

Tags: python, functional-programming

I'm trying to learn some of Python's functional aspects. I'm looking to write a comprehension that converts:

```
a = {'name': 'school a', 'grades': [3, 4, 5]}
b = {'name': 'school b', 'grades': [3, 4, 5]}
c = {'name': 'school c', 'grades': [6, 7, 8]}
```

to:

```
schools_by_grades = {3: [a, b], 4: [a, b], 5: [a, b], 6: [c], 7: [c], 8: [c]}
```

I was able to create this for `a` and `c`, but in two steps:

```
schools_by_grade = {grade: [a] for grade in a['grades']}
schools_by_grade.update({grade: [c] for grade in c['grades']})
```

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: I would go with an imperative approach (loop) combined with defaultdict

Comment: You can do it with sorted, groupby and a dict comprehension, but it's not going to be pretty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imperative is more Pythonic here:

```
d = defaultdict(lambda: [])
for school in a, b, c:
    for g in school['grades']:
        d[g].append(school)
```

Here's the "functional" approach, but as predicted it is not pretty:

```
fst = lambda (x,_): x
grade_to_school = ((g,x) for x in a,b,c for g in x['grades'])
d = { g : list(y) for g,y in groupby(sorted(grade_to_school, key=fst), key=fst) }
```

Comment: that's very kind of you to say that

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
schools_by_grades = {i: [school['name'] for school in (a, b, c) 
                         if i in school['grades']] 
                     for i in range(20) if any(i in school['grades'] 
                                               for school in (a, b, c))}
```

but you probably shouldn't.

This gives me:

```
{3: ['school a', 'school b'], 
 4: ['school a', 'school b'], 
 5: ['school a', 'school b'], 
 6: ['school c'], 
 7: ['school c'], 
 8: ['school c']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where this is so specific, I would suggest making a function for the operation.

```
def AddSchoolsByGrades(schools_by_grades, school_dict):
    # if there is a space in the name, it will take the last word of the name
    name = school_dict["name"].split(" ")[-1]
    for g in school_dict["grades"]:
        # if there is no entry for the grade, then make one
        if not g in schools_by_grades.keys():
            schools_by_grades[g] = []
        # add the name of the school to the grade
        schools_by_grades[g].append(name)
        # simple trick to remove any duplicates
        schools_by_grades[g] = list(set(schools_by_grades[g]))

a = {'name': 'school a', 'grades': [3, 4, 5]}
b = {'name': 'school b', 'grades': [3, 4, 5]}
c = {'name': 'school c', 'grades': [6, 7, 8]}

schools_by_grades = {}
AddSchoolsByGrades(schools_by_grades, a)
AddSchoolsByGrades(schools_by_grades, b)
AddSchoolsByGrades(schools_by_grades, c)
```